# Simple ARM instruction LDR base register offset question

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers, addressing-mode

```
|-----------------------------|------------------|-----------------------|
|      Executable file header |     Text Size    |      300 hex          |
|-----------------------------|------------------|-----------------------|
|                             |     Data Size    |      50 hex           |
|-----------------------------|------------------|-----------------------|
|      Text segment           |     Address      |      Instruction      |
|-----------------------------|------------------|-----------------------|
|                             | 0040 0000 hex    |  LDR r0, 8000hex (r3) |
|-----------------------------|------------------|-----------------------|
|                             | 0040 0004 hex    |  BL 00 00EChex        |
|-----------------------------|------------------|-----------------------|
|                             | ...              |  ...                  |
|-----------------------------|------------------|-----------------------|
|      Data Segment           | Address          |                       |
|-----------------------------|------------------|-----------------------|
|                             | 1000 0000hex     |     (X)               |
|-----------------------------|------------------|-----------------------|
```

This is a table illustrating how linker connects the two object files by updating the addresses in the instruction from Computer Organization & Design 4E by Patterson & Hennessy on p139.

On how the load offset was determined for the "LDR r0, 8000hex(r3)", it said that the program uses global pointer as the base register. And by assuming r4 is initialized to 1000 8000hex, we place 8000hex in the address field of LDR at address 40 0000 hex.

Can someone explain why would you put 8000hex as offset when r4 has nothing to do with r3? Or am I misunderstanding some concept here?

Comment: Sounds like a typo in the book, unless there's some other context that you're not explaining.  Google for errata for that book; there's often online errata for things that aren't yet fixed in a new edition.